# 500: Internal Server Error with java and javascript using Oracle11g

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, oracle11g

```
  public Integer getRecordCount(ErdbcrBean erdbcrBean/*String empid, String tocod*/)
  {
    SqlSession session = getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
    try
    {
      return (Integer)session.selectOne("getRecordCount", erdbcrBean);
    }catch (Exception e){
      this.logger.error("getRecordCount " + erdbcrBean, e);
      return 1;
    }finally{
      session.close();
    }
  }
```

this the DAOImpl java code I am using to see the result if the data in the database was duplicated or not.

```
 public String getRecordCount() throws Exception {
      logName = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("userName");
      
      if (logName == null)
          return "notLogin";
      else {
          /*Gson gson = new Gson();
          Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ErdbcrBean>() {
          }.getType();
          erdbcrBean = (ErdbcrBean)gson.fromJson(data, collectionType);*/
          Gson gson = new Gson();
          ErdbcrBean erdbcrBean = gson.fromJson(data, ErdbcrBean.class);
          amsBillingFacade.getBillingFacade().getR3BillHeaderDAO().execPREnable(ROLE_DESC);
          recordCount = amsBillingFacade.getBillingFacade().getR3BillHeaderDAO().getRecordCount(erdbcrBean);
          
          return SUCCESS;
      }
  }
```

This code is for the java controller to call in the DAOImpl.

```
$.getJSON('getrecordcount.html', {
                data: JSON.stringify(entries)
          }, function (record) {
              if (record > 0) {
                  $('#errorDialog').data('msg', 'Data already exist.').dialog('open');
}
}
```

this is the code that calls all the server-side to display in the front-end.

I am having difficulties with the codes above with error message:
http://10.0.2.58:7101/erdbcr/getrecordcount.html?data=%5B%7B%22usernm%22%3A%22MOERW03%22%2C%22memon%22%3A%22111111%22%2C%22itmno%22%3A%22%22%2C%22eridn%22%3A%220617439970%22%2C%22tocod%22%3A%2239%22%2C%22ssamt%22%3A%22480.00%22%2C%22mcamt%22%3A%220.00%22%2C%22ecamt%22%3A%220.00%22%2C%22orgcd%22%3A%221%22%2C%22pytyp%22%3A%221%22%2C%22prnum%22%3A%22%22%2C%22valda%22%3A%22190828%22%2C%22tsnum%22%3A%22190828%22%2C%22fapld%22%3A%221907%22%2C%22tapld%22%3A%221%22%2C%22sbpda%22%3A%22190828%22%7D%5D (500: Internal Server Error)

Comment: You'll need to find the log from the server that details exactly what the "500" error is. It could be many, many things and we cannot diagnose your problem based on what you've provided.